# Mac Programming Question: How do I detect the URL of a redirect in a WebView?

Tags: xcode, macos, redirect, webview

This is a MacOS programming question, not iOS (iPhone) programming.

I have a WebView. I can load webpages into the WebView and detect that initial load with this delegate protocol:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame decisionListener:(id)listener { NSString *urlString = [[request URL] absoluteString];
NSLog(@"%@", urlString); }
```

But the page I send it redirects immediately, and I need to see the URL that it redirects to. Unfortunately this protocol just isn't catching the redirect.

Anyone know how to detect the URL of a redirect in a WebView?

Thanks.

Comment: If it is not an iPhone programming question, do not tag it as iPhone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're a lucky guy. I've come accross the **same** problem an hour ago.

According to the WebView reference class in the Apple documentation, you have to set a delegate that conforms to the webframeloaddelegate protocol.

```
[webView setFrameLoadDelegate:object];
```

Then in object, you have to set this method:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender willPerformClientRedirectToURL:(NSURL *)URL delay:(NSTimeInterval)seconds fireDate:(NSDate *)date forFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
```

That's all!

Comment: This is for a client redirect. It will not be called for server redirects

Answer (score 4):

The `webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:` method is part of the `WebPolicyDelegate` protocol. There are two ways to do this. If you only want to know when a redirect is happening, you can use `webView:didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalLoadForFrame:` from the `WebFrameLoadDelegate` Protcol:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    NSLog(@"%@",[[[[frame provisionalDataSource] request] URL] absoluteString]);
}
```

If you want to modify the redirect, use `webView:resource:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:fromDataSource:` from the `WebResourceLoadDelegate` protocol:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)webView:(WebView *)sender resource:(id)identifier willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse fromDataSource:(WebDataSource *)dataSource {
    NSURLRequest *request = redirectResponse;
    //make any changes to and return new request
    return request;
}
```

Whichever way you do it, make sure you set the proper delegate on the webView in order to get the methods called.

Comment: But don't both of these methods get called AFTER `webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:` making it impossible to decide a navigation policy based on redirect status...?

Comment: @Jamie Perhaps I misunderstood the question. My interpretation was the redirect occurred after the policy decision, making that unimportant. Actually, re-reading now it sounds more like a client redirect as the other answer handles.